# Play Framework 2 ElasticSearch storage type

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, elasticsearch

I decided to use ElasticSearch in my Play Framework project (Play 2.0.3).

And I found and started to use [play2-elasticsearch](https://github.com/cleverage/play2-elasticsearch) plugin (thanks to autors, it's really very useful tool) which starts ElasticSearch server in local mode and uses it as a search server.

Now I want to set some additional configuration options to the ElasticSearch server. E.g. set storage type to in-memory. 
ElasticSearch documentstion [describes](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/setup/configuration.html) how to tune configuration settings in standalone mode.

But how could I perform these actions using the play plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm one of the authors of the play2-elasticsearch plugin.
I just create an issue on our github repository for add this config settings.

It's locate on this class https://github.com/cleverage/play2-elasticsearch/blob/master/module/app/com/github/cleverage/elasticsearch/IndexClient.java if you want to modify and publish the module on local before we'll release a new version.

@nboire

Answer (score 2):

Actually it's not possible to customize settings on "node" ( [issue9](https://github.com/cleverage/play2-elasticsearch/issues/9) ) but you can define settings on "index" via the "elasticsearch.index.settings" properties in application.conf

```
## Custom settings to apply when creating the index (optional)
elasticsearch.index.settings="{ analysis: { analyzer: { my_analyzer: { type: \"custom\", tokenizer: \"standard\" } } } }"
```

For settings store type, you can put settings like this :

```
elasticsearch.index.settings="{ store : { type: \"memory\" } }"
```